# Unable to use an Excel Worksheet in SSIS as a source

Tags: excel, ssis

I am trying to use an Excel 2016 Worksheet(.xlsx format) as a source for a SSIS package. When I add the excel and try selecting the name of the sheet, I do not see anything.

However, it works if I convert the Excel worksheet to .xls format. I have a lot of excel files that needs to be loaded and converting each file to .xls is not feasible.

Is there anyway this can be done with the .xlsx format itself ?

Appreciate any help on this.

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to use the ACE driver instead of JET. Just google it and install on the server with SSIS.

Comment: I think I am using ACE driver. This is what I see in the connection string. Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=P:\Changed.xlsx;Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";

Comment: Are you using 32-bit version of Excel? If so, you will need to set your SSIS project to 32-bit mode. Do this by setting the Run64BitRuntime flag to false in the configuration properties under debugging.

Comment: Nope, my excel is a 2016 64-bit one.